# Extracting Characters from a String in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I extract the first and last half of a name that is being inputted by a user? I have already split the name so that I have a list and I have set the variables `firstName` and `lastName`. If the first name has odd number of letters, the middle letter is *not included* but if the second name has an odd number of letters, the middle letter is *included*. How can I achieve that?

Example Names:

- Marie Morse -> Marse
- Logan Peters -> Loers
- Meghan Hufner -> Megner

Comment: How about some codes reflecting your try?...with examples stating your input and expected output?

Comment: Example input and output would be *really* helpful.

Comment: @zondo examples are edited in!

Comment: What if both names have odd numbers of chars?...you've included an example of that but both have their middle names char same .. 'r' ?

Comment: @IronFist look at Marie Morse. But names have odd num of chars. But we only include the middle letter with the last name, we don't do that with the first name

Comment: Another example that would be better is Helen Paige -> Heige

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
>>> def concatenate(s):
        s1,s2 = s.split()
        i,j = len(s1)//2, len(s2)//2
        return s1[:i]+s2[j:]

>>> s = 'Meghan Hufner'
>>> concatenate(s)
'Megner'
>>> s = 'Helen Paige'
>>> concatenate(s)
'Heige'
>>> s = 'Marie Morse'
>>> concatenate(s)
'Marse'
>>> s = 'Logan Peters'
>>> concatenate(s)
'Loers'
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!! I just had to work it into the function but it worked!

Comment: @katherinethegrape ... You can show that to the S.O. community by accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must name each first and last name as a string variable and do the following:

```
first = 'Marie'
last = 'Morse'
first_index = len(first)/2 +1
last_index = len(last)/2
result = first[:first_index] + last[last_index+1:]
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that really you are using either `flooring` or `ceiling` division.  To get the `ceiling` of a number, you can use the `math.ceil()` function.  The following is a little overkill for Python3, but I use `int(math.ceil...)` because in Python2, `math.ceil()` returns a float.  I also use `len(last) / 2.` because in Python2, dividing an integer by an integer always results in an integer. (floor division).  What follows assumes that `firstName` and `lastName` have already been defined:

```
import math

first_index = len(firstName) // 2               # floor division
last_index = int(math.ceil(len(lastName) / 2.)) # ceiling division

print(first[:first_index] + last[-last_index:])
```